# Translation from English to Chinese of the song "The Final Countdown"

Tags: translation

I've tried to translate the first part of the song The final countdown, can you correct me?

We're leaving together
我們離開一起。
But still it's farewell 
但是，還有告別。
And maybe we'll come back
可能我們來到這兒一邊
To earth, who can tell 
在世界，誰知道
I guess there is no one to blame
我想沒有怪一個人 
We're leaving ground (leaving ground)
 我們起飛 （起飛）
Will things ever be the same again 
東西可以是就像以前？
It's the final countdown... 
這是最後倒計時
The final countdown 
最後倒計時
Ooh oh 
噢噢
We're heading for Venus (Venus) 
我們去到金星（金星）
And still we stand tall
我們仍然在站
Cause maybe they've seen us 
因為可能這個人看看我們
And welcome us all (yeah) 
而歡迎我
With so many light years to go 
有多光年
And things to be found (to be found) 
找多東西
I'm sure that we'll all miss her so 
我知道我們想念她
It's the final countdown... 
這是最後倒計時

Comment: remember to accept an answer if you feel it's worth the acceptance! :)

Comment: translation exists on the web：googling e。g。＂The final countdown  中文＂ yields  e。g。 http://sobakome.pixnet.net/blog/post/34215983-final-countdown%EF%BC%8Deurope%28%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E%29

Answer (score 5):

Since your own translation is in Traditional Chinese, I used the same.
Besides, my translation is context-based (or I tried to make it that way), so some words are not literally translated. In case you want to learn more, further explanation is provided below.

---

```
We're leaving together
我們（要）一起離開
But still it's farewell 
但這依然是離別
And maybe we'll come back
或許我們會再回來
To earth, who can tell 
到地球上，誰能預料到？
I guess there is no one to blame
我想不該怪誰
We're leaving ground (leaving ground)
我們（將要）離開地面（離開地面）
Will things ever be the same again 
一切還會像以前一樣嗎
It's the final countdown... 
最後的倒數開始了...
The final countdown 
最後的倒數
Ooh oh 
噢噢
We're heading for Venus (Venus) 
我們正往金星前進（金星）
And still we stand tall
而我們仍然堅挺
Cause maybe they've seen us 
因為或許他們已經看到我們
And welcome us all (yeah) 
且歡迎我們（是啊）
With so many light years to go 
儘管有這麼多光年要走過
And things to be found (to be found) 
還有這麼多事物去探索（去探索）
I'm sure that we'll all miss her so 
我相信我們都會這麼想著它
It's the final countdown... 
最後的倒數開始了...
```

---

> 我們（將要）一起離開

`將要` is added to better visualize the moment.

> 誰能預料

The literal translation is `誰能告訴`, but such translation does not make sense in Chinese. Besides, in this context, tell translates to `預料`.

> 一切還會像以前一樣嗎

Things = `東西`, but in this context, the meaning is probably (every)thing, which translates to `一切`. Using `東西` itself as the subject does not make sense anyway.

> 最後的倒數開始了...

`It's the final countdown` here implies that the countdown has started, hence the phrase `開始了`.

> 而我們仍然堅挺

`Stand tall` does not literally mean `standing tall` but rather `being brave and proud`. As such, `堅挺` or `堅強` or `挺立` are some more appropriate words here.

> 還有這麼多事物去探索

`to be found` literally means `被找到`, but, in my opinion, it's probably more natural to say `去探索` or `to seek/search for`.

> 我相信我們都會這麼想著它

`sure`, in this context, means `相信`; `her(female)` translates to `它(nonliving)` because in Chinese, people usually don't use `her` to refer to, say, Earth, country, etc.

Comment: it seems as sign of respect 她 can be used for a province e。g。Sichuan，cf。《饥饿的女儿》 虹影著
第三章 第三节  starts as follows：   这城市有个动物园，有一头华南虎，已经绝灭的珍贵品种，按规定供给活物。即使灾荒日子，全省就她独一个华南虎，也得优先照顾，就象所有党的高级干 部、中级干部，按等级得到特殊待遇。
note 全省就她独一个华南虎，also refer e。g。to iciba for using 她 to express respect and love／表示敬爱
has been discussed at this site before

Comment: Ah I see, I've edited to `usually don't use`. Is province the only use case? Or has `她` been used else where?

Comment: see iciba, how about motherland, flag, Party?

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun，I translated to 文言文

We're leaving together
与子同去

But still it's farewell
顾是诀别

And maybe we'll come back
或可归来

To earth, who can tell
于斯海内，焉能知晓

I guess there is no one to blame
无以为怨

We're leaving ground (leaving ground)
飘然而去（飘然而去）

Will things ever be the same again
复如昔乎？

It's the final countdown...
终之时也

The final countdown
时乎终哉

Ooh oh
呜呼

We're heading for Venus (Venus)
同去太白

And still we stand tall
复高驻之

Cause maybe they've seen us
盖见于彼

And welcome us all (yeah)
喜迎吾等（幸哉）

With so many light years to go
穿行两界

And things to be found (to be found)
寻秘发奇

I'm sure that we'll all miss her so
众固念之

It's the final countdown...
终之时也

Comment: This is fun! I think the translation of "And still we stand tall / 亦为登高 / Cause maybe they've seen us / 或察于世" is debatable. I think the "they" refers to extraterrestrial beings on Venus? Also, "With so many light years to go" refers more to distance as opposed to time lapse; while "沧海桑田" emphasizes time.

Comment: @FangJing I'm happy that someone think it is fun.Your views sound plausible.I thought they can be seen by people from earth just because they stand tall，and that did not make sense of ''welcome us all''. I misunderstood two sentences, so the following parts was misinterpreted.Thanks, dude.

Answer (score 2):

We're leaving together
我們一起离开

But still it's farewell
但这仍是告別

And maybe we'll come back
我們或许会再回来

To earth, who can tell
回到地球——誰能知道？

I guess there is no one to blame
我觉得不怪任何人

We're leaving ground (leaving ground)
我們这就起飛 （起飛）

Will things ever be the same again
一切还会照旧吗？

It's the final countdown...
這是最後倒計時

The final countdown
最後倒計時

Ooh oh
噢噢

We're heading for Venus (Venus)
我們去往金星（金星）

And still we stand tall
我們仍然挺立

Cause maybe they've seen us
因為或许他们见过我們

And welcome us all (yeah)
而歡迎我们（耶）

With so many light years to go
有这么多光年要经过

And things to be found (to be found)
这么多事物去找寻

I'm sure that we'll all miss her so
我们一定都会那么想念她

It's the final countdown...
這是最後倒計時

Comment: 謝謝你！現在我學到漢語水平考試三，而這時很好